# boot on Windows USB installer from GRUB

Tags: usb, windows

i am on the latest version of linux ubuntu desktop (22.04.2 LTS) and i would like to boot on my windows 11 installation key. i forgot my bios password and my laptop is a TOSHIBA processor Intel® Celeron® N4000 × 2, a Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 600 (GLK 2) graphics card.

thank you for your reply

Comment: Ubuntu is not related to your BIOS password. The question is off-topic.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 is the 2022-April release; the *latest* release of Ubuntu is the 2022-October release... Windows 11 however isn't on-topic here though

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes or other issues.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to boot Ubuntu off of your Windows installation USB? That would be on topic here. Use Windows Disk Management to create about 10GB of free space. Extract the Ubuntu ISO to the USB free space and install Grub to the USB.